# Calculate timestamps in bash/perl (with keywords)

Tags: bash, perl, time, timestamp

In my company, there are different customer locations "city-01-r-01" and "city-02-r-01" and so on. So if the location is unreachable, the monitoring software generates a timestamp with the status "UNKNOWN" or "CRITICAL". When the location is reachable again, the status is shown as "OK". I need to calculate the time for how much duration the location was unreachable.

The monitoring software generates this single file (in .txt format) for all the customer locations in the following format:

- 2015-08-02 07:18:30;city-01-r-01;UNKNOWN
- 2015-08-02 07:33:25;city-01-r-01;OK
- 2015-08-03 12:56:50;city-02-r-01;CRITICAL
- 2015-08-03 13:02:49;city-02-r-01;OK

I need to extract the above information and calculate the unreachability for every location from the .txt file.

My output should be another .txt file in the following format:
(script can either be in bash or perl or any other scripting language)

- city-01-r-01 was unreachable for ___ (minutes) ____ (seconds) on ____(date)
- city-02-r-01 was unreachable for ___ (minutes) ____ (seconds) on ____(date)

I googled a bit today and got the idea that I need to use IFS (for reading line by line) and a while/do loop to achieve this. But, I'm not sure how to achieve the results.

Comment: _These records are stored in a different text file_: What record is stored in what file? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Timestamps are stored in a different text file (.txt). I need to extract information from this text file.

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear. Do you have one timestamp per file? If yes, which one do you chose when you want to calculate the difference between the `UNKNOWN` and `OK` markers? Do you have several timestamps per file? If yes do you want to compute these time differences on a per file basis? Please try to understand that we do not know anything about your problem and try to give enough information.

Comment: @IP_Engr, what is your desired output?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet .. the question is updated, hope it clears the doubts now.

Comment: @glennjackman .. the question is updated, hope it clears the doubts now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple with Perl using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my %outages;

my $time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($timestamp, $city, $status) = split /;/;

  my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, $time_format);

  if ($status ne 'OK') {
    $outages{$city} = $time;
  } else { # status is now ok
    my $duration = $time - $outages{$city};
    say "city $city was unreachable for ",
        $duration->pretty, ' on ', $outages{$city}->date;
  }
}

__END__
2015-08-02 07:18:30;city-01-r-01;UNKNOWN
2015-08-02 07:33:25;city-01-r-01;OK
2015-08-03 12:56:50;city-02-r-01;CRITICAL
2015-08-03 13:02:49;city-02-r-01;OK
```

(For simplicity, I've put the data in the `DATA` filehandle. Fixing that to read it from an external file is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with perl, python, SQLite, C, C++, java, tcl, bash... Here is one with GNU awk, the GNU Swiss knife for text file processing:

```
$ cat csv2ts.awk
BEGIN { FS = ";" }
{
    t = $1;
    gsub(/[-:]/, " ", t);
    t = mktime(t);
}
$3 == "UNKNOWN" || $3 == "CRITICAL" { c[$2] = t }
$3 == "OK" {
    d = t - c[$2];
    printf("%s was unreachable for %d (minutes) %d (seconds) on %s (date)\n",
           $2, d / 60, d % 60, strftime("%F", t));
}
$ awk -f csv2ts.awk data.csv > data.txt
$ cat data.txt
city-01-r-01 was unreachable for 14 (minutes) 55 (seconds) on 2015-08-02 (date)
city-02-r-01 was unreachable for 5 (minutes) 59 (seconds) on 2015-08-03 (date)
```

The awk script is stored in file `csv2ts.awk`, your original data in `data.csv` and the output result in `data.txt`. The awk script uses ';' as field separator (`FS = ";"`). It computes the timestamp (in seconds) of each record, using the first field (`gsub`, `mktime`). It builds an array of timestamps (`c`) indexed by customer locations (field #2). The date of the incident is computed from the timestamp of the second event (`OK`) using `strftime`. The rest should be easy to understand.

Please note that your problem is underspecified:

- are the records for city C consecutive in the file?
- what exact output format do you want for the date?
- what happens when the non-reachability period crosses day boundaries?
- what if, for a given location, the sequence of events is not UNKNOWN,OK or CRITICAL,OK but anything else, like OK,OK or UNKNOWN,CRITICAL?
- what if, for a given location, the first event is OK?
- what if, for a given location, the last event is not OK?

If you complete your specification, adapting the awk script should be reasonably easy.

Comment: Note: requires GNU awk for the mktime/strftime functions